# Example of using APFS local snapshots to backup (snapshot), diff and restore a folder in macOS 12+?

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine, restore, monterey

I have a folder I want to experiment with. Unfortunately the folder is several hundred gigabytes and I don't want to spend time backing it up again and restoring it if something goes sideways on me.

APFS makes local snapshots and you can restore these via `Time Machine.app` and `tmutil`. I'd like to understand how to better use the shell-based `tmutil` to have fine grained control over backing up (snapshotting) a folder/directory, `diff`'ing it and restoring it (if necessary).

Can someone provide an example of performing these operations for an example folder?

Comment: You can clone the folder in Finder (command-D), which shouldn't take much space. Then after the experiment, you can delete the original folder and rename the duplicate.

Comment: The reason why you don't want to use snapshots for this is if you change part of file A, you can't copy that part over to reverse the operation; you have to copy the whole file A (version 1) from the snapshot to the folder. If you clone the folder, though, you can just delete file A (version 2) and move file A (version 1) over.

Comment: I actually think you're wrong here @Joy Jin. From further playing with the functionality I have successfully done what I've asked and diff'ing the folders and/or rsync seems to rectify the situation quite cleanly. I will answer the question with the process (albeit clunkier than I like in terms of the tooling) once I give it a production run and document it cleanly.